# Как очистить форму от рисунка нажатием кнопки?

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(20,30), new Point(40, 150));
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(220, 30), new Point(240, 150));
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(20, 30), new Point(220,30));
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(40, 150), new Point(240, 150));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вызвать `Refresh` или `Invalidate`